# Enter/update/exit join pattern Bostock example doesn't seem to work with new data "inserted" at position 0

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Following along with Bostock's selection.join example (https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join) I run into an issue with enter and update where the correct .attr() are not applied. I must be having some fundamental underlying mis-understanding since this quite closely mirrors the example but don't behave in the same manner.

The simplified version I created removes the loop and uses fixed data sets for simplicity.

Here is the example data update sequence which results in unexpected result/colors for items which are updated/entered:

```
[1, 2, 3] -> all values are green
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3] -> -1, 0 should be green and 1, 2, 3 should be black.
```

What I actually get is

```
-1, 0, 1 -> are black 
2, 3 -> green
```

It appears almost as if it only looks at the index and doesn't actually look at the value.

Here is the block with my example code:
https://bl.ocks.org/aitee/5627fefb443ddccc7aa7f609780aaeca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**: You're missing a [key function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data).

If you look at Bostock's example, you'll see the he uses a key function:

```
selection.data(randomLetters(), d => d)
```

However, your code doesn't:

```
selection.data(data)
```

Therefore, the result is the expected one. If you don't use a [key function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data)...

> ... then the first datum in data is assigned to the first selected element, the second datum to the second selected element, and so on. A key function may be specified to control which datum is assigned to which element, replacing the default join-by-index, by computing a string identifier for each datum and element.

Here is your code with a key function: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/1682dca153d872b445e7060421a5a824/d7c8da29ee7692c71bac3714e9bae051f033cd61